# Spring Data CosmosTemplate create query with System Functions

Tags: java, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are trying to implement a query with cosmosTemplate from spring-data-cosmosdb project.
The query has the following syntax:
`"select * from movie where ARRAY_CONTAINS(movie.countries, @country)"`. 
CosmosTemplate accepts DocumentQuery object, that is build upon Criteria object. Criteria object supports a small subset of basic predicates like `in`, `or`, `is equal` and etc., but doesn't have `array_contains` predicate. 
At the moment the query is performed by using cosmos client(from sdk), instead of cosmosTemplate.
This brings us two issues:

1. We have to mix the code by using cosmosTemplate and cosmos client together.
2. Since we have complex parameterized queries that use system functions, we have to concatenate sql query string and gather sql parameters.

How queries like this should be handled with cosmosTemplate and is that even possible?

P.S we are using com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter:2.2.5 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research in [azure sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/), I've found that at the moment not all system functions are supported by cosmosTemplate.
List of supported system functions can be found there:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/data/cosmos/core/query/CriteriaType.java

If you wan't to write query that uses system function, that isn't in the list in the link above, you can use either `@Query` annotation or directly use cosmos client instead of cosmosTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

In the current GA release you will have to use the Client and template together like you mentioned.

The latest beta release includes support for QueryAnnotation Using annotated queries in repositories. Following is an example:

```
@Query(value = "select * from c where c.firstName = @firstName and c.lastName = @lastName")
List<User> getUsersByTitleAndValue(@Param("firstName") int firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

Comment: This is new feature and is not compatible with our spring-boot version. Will try it though after upgrade.

Comment: I will soon publish a sample app with all the new capabilities. Will let you know. It will be great If you accept my answer ! :)

Comment: @RCT, did you get a chance to publish the sample app?

Answer (score 2):

Ravi's answer is correct. To create custom queries directly from Spring Data connector, there are current two options.

First, you can follow the instructions in the "Custom Query" section of this document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb

which guide you through using the Java SDK CosmosClient directly. The current GA release of Spring Data connector does not have @Query annotation which would enable custom query annotation, that is why you need to use the Java SDK directly.

Second, upgrade to the latest beta which enables @Query annotation

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-spring-data-cosmos

Sample code for this will be released in the next few days, and the GA release is scheduled for 9/30 so it is not a long wait.